# Using is_unique form validation causes "The USERNAME field must contain a unique value." error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working for a homework which requires the users to create an account and requires username and password. I'm using is_unique[users.user_name] to save only unique usernames but I won't able pass the validation. I keep getting "The USERNAME field must contain a unique value." error message.

```
<?php
class Register extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

  }

  public function index(){
    $data['title'] = 'Register';
    $this->load->view('register', $data);
  }

  public function verify(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtfname', 'FIRST NAME', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtlname', 'LAST NAME', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtmname', 'MIDDLE NAME', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtgender', 'GENDER', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtbday', 'BIRTHDAY', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtcountry', 'COUNTRY', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txthouse_no', 'FLOOR / DEPT / BUILDING / HOUSE NO', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtstreet', 'STREET', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtcity_province', 'CITY / PROVINCE', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtpostal_code', 'POSTAL CODE', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtphone', 'PHONE', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtemail', 'E-MAIL ADDRESS', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtuser', 'USERNAME', 'required|trim|is_unique[users.user_name]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtpass', 'PASSWORD', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtrepass', 'RE-TYPE ADDRESS', 'required|matches[txtpass]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
      $this->load->model('register_model');
      $isRegistered = $this->register_model->register();

      if($isRegistered){
        $data['title'] = 'Registration Successful';
        $data['message'] = 'Please check your email to activate your account.';
      } else {
        $data['title'] = 'Registration Failed';
        $data['message'] = 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
      }

      $this->load->view('registration_message', $data);

    } else {
      $this->index();
    }

  }

}
?>



<?php
class register_model extends CI_Model{
  public function construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }

  public function register(){
    $personal_info = array(
        'cust_lname' => $this->input->post('txtlname'),
        'cust_fname' => $this->input->post('txtfname'),
        'cust_mname' => $this->input->post('txtmname'),
        'cust_bday' => $this->input->post('txtbday'),
        'cust_gender' => $this->input->post('txtgender'),
        'cust_country' => $this->input->post('txtcountry'),
        'cust_house_no' => $this->input->post('txthouse_no'),
        'cust_street' => $this->input->post('txtstreet'),
        'cust_area' => $this->input->post('txtarea'),
        'cust_city_province' => $this->input->post('txtcity_province'),
        'cust_postal_code' => $this->input->post('txtpostal_code'),
        'cust_phone' => $this->input->post('txtphone'),
        'cust_email' => $this->input->post('txtemail'),
        'cust_dateRegistered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      );
    $isCustomer_added = $this->db->insert('customers', $personal_info);

    $userAccess_info = array(
      'user_name' => $this->input->post('txtuser'),
      'user_pass' => md5($this->input->post('txtpass')),
      'user_lvl' => 2,
      'cust_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
      'isApproved' => 0
      );
    $isUser_added = $this->db->insert('users', $userAccess_info);

    if($isCustomer_added && $isUser_added){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I expect to save the user info in the database but I keep getting "The USERNAME field must contain a unique value." validation error message.

Comment: Side tip: You don't need the very last `} else {` in `register()` (take advantage of the return early principle - your teacher will love it), or even better `return ($isCustomer_added && $isUser_added);`

Comment: "The USERNAME field must contain a unique value." are you sure the username your trying to use isn't already taken in the database? that's what unique is all about

Comment: the users table are blank so any input in the username field should be valid but I still getting the validation error.

Comment: Are you sure that the field is `user_name` and not `username`?

Comment: hi zanderwar, thanks for you suggestion but I already figured it out. I have to load the database in the register controller constructor method this->load->database() so that the validation is_unique will be able to access and check the database if the entered username already exist.

Comment: No problem, to really impress your teacher, follow these standards: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ <3 good luck with it!